# Handling Multiple Optional File Uploads with C# - .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file, upload

I have **8** different files I'd like to upload.

Currently I'm using the code below. The following is just a snippet for uploading the first 2 files. It works great, but is soon going to start getting ugly as I start to add more and more file upload fields.

**WebForm:**
`<p>
  Thumb 1:<br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="img1sml" type="file" name="img1sml" runat="server" />
  </p>
  <p>
  Image 1:<br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="img1" type="file" name="img1" runat="server" />
  </p>...`

**CodeBehind:** `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(img1sml.FileName))
            {
                img1sml.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + img1sml.FileName));
                img1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + img1.FileName));
                // Create command 
                comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO news (title, img1sml, img1, img1sml) VALUES (@Title, @img1sml, @img1)", conn);
                // Add command parameters`

I'd like to be able to test (in an efficient way) if each of the 8 **file upload fields** is empty or not. If they are empty I'd like to skip the file upload and db insertion and move to the next file.

How would you recommend I do this?

Many many thanks for any guidance with this.

Comment: what do you mean by moving to the next file, if you are asking how to check if the 8 file uploads are empty?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to check all 8 fields and then only upload those fields that have a file in them.

Comment: ok, well, by uploading you mean saving the files and executing that command right? because when you make the postback the files are uploaded

Comment: Hey. Yes, sorry, I mean saving the files :) I'd like to save ALL files where the user has selected files to save. The user might not save all 8 files and only (for example) 6, so I'd like to make sure it loops through all the files, and these are saved. I'd THEN like to insert the files saved into the correct columns in the table of my database, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through a collection of posted files in the request object, called Request.Files

```
    foreach (string key in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[key];
        if (file.ContentLength != 0)
        {
          file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + file.FileName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Pablo. As you may understand, I'm very new to C# and .NET. How do I use my `img1sml.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + img1sml.FileName));` in this foreach loop? So it loops through all files?

Comment: each file is accessible within the foreach block, through the file object, I would create a function that takes a HttpPostedFile object and do the operations you want

Comment: Many thanks for your help and patience Pablo. I will add this and see how I get on. Back in a minute :)

Comment: Hi Pablo. I use this code and I get the following error: `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'.` on the line with `foreach (HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files)`. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: sorry Request.Files iterates trough the keys of the collection not the values

Comment: Thanks so much again for all your help Pablo. I've made the ammendment provided and here is the new error: `The given path's format is not supported.` I **really** appreciate all your help so far.

Comment: Hi. The full path is '/ATHI/Images/' but I've tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: do u have a unix or linux machine?, because if you have a windows machine you need to convert that path, with Server.MapPath

Comment: Do you need my full path up to the C: drive? Would this help?

Comment: Remove the first /     Server.MapPath("ATHI/Images/" + file.FileName) that should give you an absolute windows path.

Comment: I have removed the first but unfortunately it still gives the same error: `file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("ATHI/Images/" + file.FileName));`

Comment: what i mean is if ATHI is part of an application path you don't have to include it, if you access the page by typing http://myweb.com/ATHI then remove ATHI/

Comment: it would help me more if you show me how do you access the web app it does not matter if it's a local address

Comment: It's strange as this works fine: `img1sml.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/" + img1sml.FileName));` but this does not: `file.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + file.FileName));`

Comment: Don't include ATHI that doesn't form part of the Relative Path.

Comment: OK. I won't include it. Just to confirm, I'm currently using this but still have the errors: `file.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + file.FileName));`

Comment: is the result of Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + file.FileName) a valid windows path?

Comment: Sadly, for this I still get `System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.` :'(

Comment: if you are using an older windows server and the result of the Server.MapPath function is too long, or contains invalid characters then i would probably give you a similar error, try uploading a file with a simple name like 1.jpg

Comment: I'm uber tired and have to leave the computer. Many, many thanks for your efforts this evening. I will take a look in the morning with fresh eyes and see how I fair. Thank you again. I'll let you know if I win :D