# Multiple Optional File Saves

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, upload, save

I have 8 **file** fields in my form and when the user submits the form, I would like to loop through all these fields and 'save' any files to my server.

Can someone show me how I can do this?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling Multiple Optional File Uploads with C# - .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145817/handling-multiple-optional-file-uploads-with-c-net)

Comment: Apologies. That one was getting a bit messy. I can return to it if need be. I just wanted to start afresh today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

http://csharptuning.blogspot.com/2007/05/uploading-multiple-files.html

I hope its help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Anand. The zip at that link seems to be down :'( I actually would prefer to state 8 as the maximum limit of files as I want to use the file names saved and add them in the database later.